# How to take 1 week dump using Query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump

I have write one query but its not working as JS file. I want to take dump of this find Script.

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 -d DBname -c Coll --queryFile "Script.js"
```

using 3.4 Version of MongoDB.

Pls help.

```
db.getSiblingDB('DBName')
var date=new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
Date()
db.Collection.find({"_updatedAt":{ $lt: date}});
```

Comment: Its got Resolved actually I was using Mongo.EXE of 4+ version and DB was at 3.6 that why it was not running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this,

```
var today = new Date();
var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
var firstDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first));
var lastDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first + 6));


db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        date: {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: '$date'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "date": {
            $lt: lastDayWeek,
            $gt: firstDayWeek
        }
    }
}])
```

Also to execute your script use [--queryFile](http://--queryFile)

Comment: Soham Thankyou for your Ans but My Script is working in studio 3t but its not working as JS script. Can you Help into that.

Comment: Do we require add print with all column names to data get print.